# Corona SDK Trouble with Scene Change

Tags: events, lua, storyboard, coronasdk, listeners

**ADDED LINK TO STORYBOARD PROJECT WITH ERROR**

**Project** - http://forums.coronalabs.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=2062

**original topic** - http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/46884-scene-change-pleeeeease-help/

I have tried changing scenes so many times, it either makes the player glitch and move around anywhere, or I have attempt to applyforce (blah blah blah (don't remember)) a nil value, or bad argument expected proxy, and all this other crazy stuff. To keep things simpler for the both of us I've sent you the code without the scene changing as it is a complete mess. I've been trying to do this for weeks but can't get it right. I know it feels like I'm not doing anything by asking you what seems like impossible code, but I can't get the scene to change without tons of errors.

Please tell me the code to do:

```
local function onCollision( event )
  if event.phase == "began" then
    -- go to nex​t lua/scene completely obliterating this one as 
    -- if I'm opening a whole new game
  end
  return true
end
```

If you really don't want to do the code for me I'm willing to pay at this point

I just want to get past this... please

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start( )

physics.setGravity( 0, 15 ) -- set x & y gravity to 0

local background = display.newImage( "background.jpg" )
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY

local ground = display.newImage( "ground.png" )
ground.x = display.contentCenterX
ground.y = 480
physics.addBody( ground, "static", {density=1, friction=1, bounce=0.3 } )

local flag = display.newImage( "flag.png" )
flag.x = display.contentCenterX
flag.y = 50
physics.addBody( flag, "static", {density=0, friction=1, bounce=0.3 } )

local player = display.newImage( "player.png" )
player.x = display.contentCenterX
player.y = 425
physics.addBody( player, {density=0, friction=1, bounce=0.3 } )
player.isFixedRotation = true

system.setAccelerometerInterval( 100.0 )

local tiltSpeed = 2

local function onTilt( event )
        movementX = tiltSpeed * event.xGravity
        player.x = player.x + movementX
                -- prevent player from moving offscreen
        if player.x <= 30 then 
                player.x = 30 
        elseif player.x >= 310 then
                player.x = 310
        end
end

local function onCollision( event )
  if event.phase == "began" then
    -- go to next lua/scene completely obliterating this one as if I'm opening a whole new game
  end
  return true
end

local function onScreenTouch( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        -- make player jump
        player:applyForce( 0, -4, player.x, player.y )
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", onTilt )
Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", onScreenTouch )
flag:addEventListener("collision", onCollision )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot leave the current scene during a collision. What you can do though, is make a timer call a function 1 millisecond after the collision. 
Try this code instead for your collision event detector:

```
local function onCollision( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
       function(sceneChange)
           storyboard.gotoScene(Your next scene here")
       end
       timer.performWithDelay(1,sceneChange,1)
    end
    return true
end
```

'Hope that helps! Keep coding!

Comment: on another note, you should really have all your graphics in a group, so that it is easier to transfer between storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function that changes proceeds to the next scene

```
local function changeScene()
  composer.gotoScene("nextScene")
end

local function onCollision( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
     changeScene()
    end
    return true
end
```

I suggest using [composer api](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/01/21/introducing-the-composer-api-plus-tutorial/) its more updated than storyboard api.

As a advice, remove all eventlisteners you have called, especially those runtime eventlisteners you have. Even if you change scene, that event will still trigger, hence giving you and error because it reference it deleted. Rule of thumb, "If you don't need it, remove it."